# What's supposed to happen when I click on my network reputation chart?

Tags: bug

First off, the network rep chart is pretty sweet. Here's mine:

https://stackexchange.com/users/21/michael-haren?tab=reputation

As you hover you get a nice tooltip. Lassoing the chart appears to be broken for me in Chrome 26 on Windows 7.

On a related note, **clicking the links in the legend** is also broken in Chrome 26/Windows7 (for me); my cursor indicates they are clickable but clicking them doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Comment: Is this working for anyone running Chrome? Which version?

Comment: Works on my Chrome 26 - Windows 7. Works as a toggle.

Comment: No dice in incognito mode, either (no extensions)

Comment: This has been broken for a while in Firefox as well.  Also in the rep bar graph.  It used to work, click + drag + release used to select.  The release no longer works.  It still works in IE10.

Answer (score 1):

For me it removes that line and rescales the graph so I can see more details about the lines that are left.

It may help to know your browser. I'm using Opera 12.15.

Comment: OK, it works in IE9, not my Chome 26. Thanks! I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro the toll-tippish thing. But I know the other one.

When you hover over the site name, the corresponding rep-graph is emphasised (gets a thicker line) so that you can better discern it.

And when you click on it, the site's reputation graph gets removed from or readded to the graph.

Comment: That's more of what I expected, but it's not working for me.

Comment: What browser? NoScript?

Comment: OK, it works in IE9, not my Chome 26. Thanks! I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox if you click and drag the graph it rescales like so and a Reset Zoom button appears [image: zoom]. When I click on one of the keys then it toggles between grey where the data for that site is not shown on the graph and normal where the data is shown on the graph [image: lots of lines].